# How do you make python choose input at random then

Tags: python

I am currently working on my python skills for my GCSE's, that is coming up next year. My teacher gave our class a range of tasks to test our skills on python. So far, I have completed most of the tasks but I've had multiple problems with this current task.

**This is the task as follows**

> A printing shop runs 16 batches (jobs) every week and each batch requires a sheet of
>   special colour-proofing paper of size **A5**.
>
> Every Monday morning, the foreman opens a new envelope, containing a large sheet of the special paper with size **A1**.
>
> He proceeds to cut it in half, thus getting two sheets of size **A2**. Then he cuts one of them
>   in half to get two sheets of size **A3** and so on until he obtains the A5-size sheet needed for
>   the first batch of the week.
>
> All the unused sheets are placed back in the envelope.
>   At the beginning of each subsequent batch, he takes from the envelope one sheet of paper
>   at random. If it is of size A5, he uses it.
>
> If it is larger, he repeats the ‘cut-in-half’ procedure until
>   he has what he needs and any remaining sheets are always placed back in the envelope.

In conclusion, I am not sure what to do next but any answers/tips would be helpful. I would upload more screenshots of my errors but since I'm new to this website, I can't add more than two links.

[image: img1] [image: img2]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmxNr.png)[4][3]

Comment: The reason why you can't upload screenshots of code/errors is because it is more useful if you post them here formatted as `code` . That way we can copy it into our own compilers/interpreters and figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Presumably the task is to simulate this happening?

Comment: In your example 3, you declare an empty list `paperCount`, then try to access a random element 0 thru 5 of that list -- but it's still empty.